# Format date of X axis in material Google Chart

Tags: reactjs, google-visualization, date-formatting

I am working with **Google Charts** on my **React** application using [React-Google-Charts](https://github.com/rakannimer/react-google-charts) for this.

For the chart types, I am using the material versions of different Google Charts, such as *Line* instead of *LineChart*, *Bar* instead of *ColumnChart* and so on.

I use these types of charts as I need to have multiple 'Y' axes at the same time, and the material charts allow me to do this without overlappings of the axes (with the classic charts, when putting more than two 'Y' axes, they overlap).

However, my 'X' axis is formed by dates, and these dates have a really annoying and not useful format in the material charts.

This is how the dates are shown in the material *Bar* chart:

[image: Material version of the chart]

Instead of this, I would like a more informative date format, something like 'MMM dd, yyyy' for example.

---

*Edited due to WhiteHat's comment*

As it has been noted in the comments, Google has a [track list](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143) of the options that do not work with *material* charts, and at first I was using one of these options, so of course it didn't work.

Now I've changed it to an option that is not mentioned in the track list, but it still doesn't work with my *material* charts:

```
hAxis: {
    format: 'MMM dd'
};
```

---

***Found the solution by myself:***

The problem was that I needed to convert these options, which are not in the *material* form, by using a function that Google provides for each type of chart. In the *Bar* chart case for instance, I would have to use `google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options)` to convert these options.

As I am using a React wrapper for my code, *react-google-charts*, this cannot be done in a very obvious way, but [here](https://github.com/RakanNimer/react-google-charts/issues/157) someone proposes the perfect solution for it.

Comment: check here, there are several options that don't work on _material_ charts --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

Comment: Thank you for the comment, it actually seems that `hAxes.gridlines.units` doesn't work on _material_ charts, which is what I was trying to use.